# Add single unit of time to timestamp for use in Blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, java-me, time

How can I add a single unit of time to timestamp, just like "add method" of Java "Calendar" class but by using Blackberry API set
Can anyone please help me with source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still can use [Calendar](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/java/util/Calendar.html) in BlackBerry:

```
class Scr extends MainScreen {
    public Scr() {
        Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        add(new LabelField("now:"));
        add(new LabelField(date.toString()));
        add(new LabelField("past month:"));
        add(new LabelField(addDateTime(date, Calendar.MONTH, 1).toString()));
    }

    public Date addDateTime(Date date, int field, int addValue) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(date);
        int value = c.get(field);
        c.set(field, value + addValue);
        return c.getTime();
    }
}
```